# Is it OK to try to contact the person who may have cast a revenge down-vote on my post?

Tags: discussion

Today I commented on an answer and pointed out some mistakes. After that the answer got 2 down-votes, but I didn't do that. Then I got down-vote on my other early post, which I suppose it's revenge down-vote from the OP who's answer I commented on. I know votes are random; I still tried to confirm that and I think I'm pretty sure about that.

So I want to explain to the OP that I didn't cast the down-vote, so I left a comment on his other post. A moderator told me that it's not the appropriate behaviour.

So my question is:

1. Is it OK to contact other person about such vote issue? I think it could be solved via communication, is it wrong?
2. If yes, then what should be the appropriate method? I know that leaving irrelevant comment on any posts is not appropriate.
3. If no, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Yes, right. Just don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of MSE - [How should I handle possible revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106704/how-should-i-handle-possible-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: Yeah - these people are already acting irrationally and immorally.  Engaging with them will just end up in a street brawl.

Comment: I usually prefix "I didn't downvote, but" to my comment, but that only makes sense when there's already a downvote.

Comment: @Dukeling I wanted to edit my comment to add that; but the post is soon deleted so...

Comment: @songyuanyao the kinds of people who engage in this revenge downvoting are not rational.  You say hello, they will stab you.  Best to just stay away from them:)

Comment: @MartinJames I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: you have 74k rep why do you care about a single downvote?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I didn't cast downvote, and maybe he's thinking I did that. So I think maybe I could explain to him. It might be meaningless...

Comment: I think they'd probably still blame you for the down votes. They'd just say that others down voted because of your comment.

Comment: @BSMP Yes. I realized what I wanted to do doesn't make much sense now.

Comment: @MartinJames Especially after my comment the man edited his answer so I did help him to improve it..

Comment: @WhatsThePoint And I care about it because it's not a normal vote, I suppose it's a revenge one. I just think I might could solve the issue via private communication.. Yes it seems meaningless.

Comment: @songyuanyao or it’s just a coincidence that you got a downvote shortly after you left the comment?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I don't think so; I confirmed it by some other means..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 1. Is it OK to contact other person about such vote issue? I think it could be solved via communication, is it wrong?

No, it's not OK to contact the other person. While you may think you're sure who down-voted, there's a good chance you'll be wrong and contact the wrong person.

> 3. If no, are there anything I can do?

Flag the post for moderator attention using the "other" option. We can investigate and ask for the votes to be invalidated if there is evidence of serial voting.